# How can I make my code, that defines variables based on a list that is returned by a function, look nicer?

Tags: python

Is there a way to do in a nicer way the following thing in Python ?

```
def proving():
    a = 4*5
    b = 1*9
    results = [a,b]
    return results

results = proving()
a = results[0]
b = results[1]
```

I would like to make a function that makes some calculations and then obtain the values of the variables of interest from this function. Yes, I could simply write `a = 4*5` and `b = 1*9` but I like the idea to wrap everything into a function. On the other hand, I think that defining the variables *a* and *b* as `a = results[0]` and `b = results[1]` is a little bit ugly (expecially if the number of variables defined in this way increases...).

Comment: To expand on some comments below, if the rest of your code is expecting a list, then returning a list could be useful.  But without the rest of your code, we don't know.  And using a function to get `a=20` and `b=9` doesn't make sense.  Clearly, your actual code is doing something else within `proving`, but without that context, we can't help make that aspect better either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could return everything as a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences). Using a concept called **unpacking**, you can then just extract the values you need.

```py
def proving():
    a = 4*5
    b = 1*9
    return a, b

a, b = proving()
```

You could go one step further and eliminate the variables inside the function:

```py
def proving():
    return 4*5, 1*9

a, b = proving()
```

BTW, this works outside functions, and with lists too:

```py
a, b = 4*5, 1*9
c, d = [3*6, 2*7]
```

Comment: BTW, I'm not very sure if this question is a good fit for this community, but here's one answer anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer ! I do not understand why this question should not belong to this community.. is this SE website for making cleaner (and so pretty) codes ?

Comment: I've generally seen that asking "how do I improve my code?" is better than "how do I improve *[aspect X]* of my code?" In your case, *[aspect X]* would be getting variables from a function. Besides, your title is framed as "How do I *[do Y]*?" which is also not encouraged here. That said, I'm not a veteran on this Stack Exchange, so I could be incorrect.

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation... I tried to change at least the title.